# Spring-MVC: Disabling comments in view output?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

In JSF i can disable rendering comments in view by setting `javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS` context-param. Is something similar in Spring-MVC i can use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a feature of the rendering toolkit you use, not a feature of the MVC Framework.

- If you have JSP comments (`<%-- --%>`), then will be "removed" by default.
- If you use JSPX (not JSP) the HTML comments `<!-- -->` will be removed by default too.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about it. I replaced all `<!-- -->` with `<%-- --%>` and comments disappeared :)